# How to construct a function continuous only on an interval $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Please give an example of a function which is continuous only on an interval $[a,b]$

Comment: Presumeably, you want $f$ defined on all of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes, I want a function f:R\to R such that it is continuous on [0,1] only.

Comment: Make the graph look like $\backslash$_/. Now alter the slanted bits...

Answer (score 5):

Let $F\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a bounded function which is not continuous at any point, and $F(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0& x\in[a,b]\\ F(x)\cdot(x-a)& x<a\\ F(x)\cdot(b-x)& x>b\end{cases}$$ I leave you with the task of showing this is a continuous function only on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Surely your example may be discontinuous at $a$ and/or $b$. Making $F$ bounded and considering $|(x-b)(x-a)|F(x)$ will work.

Comment: yes, I also think so.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: In fact one only has to require that $F$ is bounded on $(a-\delta_1,a)$ and $(b,b+\delta_2)$ for some $\delta_i>0$.

Comment: Of course, that goes without saying. We can even take $\delta_1=\delta_2$ without loss of generality :).

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Of course, that goes without saying. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{ if } x\in [0,1] \\
|x| & \text{ if } x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus(\mathbb{Q}\cup[0,1]) \\
0 & \text{ o.w., if } x < 0 \\
1 & \text{ o.w.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: will it be continuous at a and b?

Comment: Yes (the only possible issue would be at $0^-$ and $1^+$, but the right limit at $0$ exists and is $0$ (similarly, the left limit at $1$ exists and is $1$)).